# Where are default arguement of function stored in memory, Is it put along with function address in code segment?

Tags: c++, memory

`void display(char = '*', int = 3);`  where is '*' and 3 stored.
Code taken from https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/default-argument

Comment: Built right into the code most likely. There will be some instruction like `mov reg 3` that slaps a three into some register..

Comment: As they say, this is implementation-dependent.     The arguments may, potentially, be stored nowhere.   For example, in your case, the compiler may see a statement of the form `display();`   and magically translate that into `display(' ', 3)` before doing any other forms of code translation.  That doesn't necessarily require storing the arguments anywhere.

Comment: There are no default arguments in C. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: The compiler will add them, during the build phase, as if they were specified

Comment: C and C++ are different? How? they both start with the letter C! Next you'll be telling me that chihuahuas and chrysanthemums are different.

Comment: They aren't stored anywhere, they are only in the source code definitions, they don't exist in the compiled program

Comment: @user4581301   You mean they're not?????   ;-)

Comment: @user4581301 They are identical in the same way as cars and carpets are. And ... No! I won't accept carpets with wheels!

Answer (score 1):

The way default arguments work is rather primitive. Whenever you call the function:

```
display('x',42);
display('x');
display();
```

Then the default arguments are replaced at the call site, ie the three calls are equivalent to:

```
display('x',42);
display('x',3);
display('*',3);
```

Default arguments aren't first class citizens. They are not stored along with the function. They are no different from "normal" parameters you pass to a function.

Comment: This is one possible implementation. It's equally valid for the compiler to create two function bodies, one with the default argument filled in and one parameter less. How would you tell the difference (in portable C++?)

Comment: @MSalters if one cannot tell the difference it falls under the as-if-rule. Nevertheless I think this answer is fine as mental model of whatever the compiler actually does that will have equivalent efffect